# Confidence Interval around prediction with bootstrapping

Tags: neural-networks, training, prediction

I want to generate a confidence interval around my prediction (vector) $\hat{y}$. I have implemented the following procedure. However, I am not sure whether this makes sense in a statistical way:

1. I have a data set. First I split it into a 80% training set (2000 measurements), 10% valdidation set and 10% testing set (250 measurements)
2. I resample B ($\sim 100$) training sets from the original training set with replacement.

   - For each of the B training datasets I train the model $b$ and
     validate it 
     (everytime I use the same validation set).
   - I use the testset from point 1. and make a prediction $\hat{y}_i^b$ 
     (so everytime I use the same test set, since I need the predictions for the same input values)
3. I calculate the average of the $B$ predictions. $$\bar{\hat{y}}_i=\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\hat{y}_i^b$$.
4. I calculate the variance  ($i\in [1,250]$) 
   $$\sigma_{\hat{y}_i}^2=\frac{1}{B-1}\sum_{b=1}^B(\hat{y}_i^b -\bar{\hat{y}}_i)^2$$
5. I **guess** the $95\%$ confidence interval for the prediction $\hat{y}_i$ is $$\hat{y}_i\in \bar{\hat{y}}_i\pm z_{0.025}\frac{\sigma_{\hat{y}_i}}{\sqrt{B}}$$
   with $z_{0.025}=1.96$
6. If I sort the $\hat{y}_i$ values and plot it together with the upper
   and lower bound, I will get the prediction curve with a CI.

My biggest uncertainty relates to step 5). I read in a book [Supervised Classification:Quite a Brief Overview, Marco Loog](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/B9780128117880000056?token=BDF247F6F2EAA467DDC6127D21F373AD489E541F3F7A96B8F821A56B5A165A70F45B047108765812F3559C20E3FEBDFC):

> When the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is known and the parent population is normally distributed **or $N>30$** the $100(1-\alpha)$ CI for the population mean is given by the symmetrical distribution for the standardized normal distribution $z$
>   $$\mu\in \bar{x}\pm z_{a/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$$

Is it correct to say here $N=B$ (number of bootstrap models or number of resampled trainingsets or number of estimators $\hat{y}_i^b$ ). Does the procedure make sense?